# Hide group if all its children are hidden

Tags: jquery

I want to to hide entire div.group or H2 tag only if all elements class.element in the current div.group are hidden.

Thanks.

```
<div class="group_container">
    <div class="group">
        <h2>Group1</h2>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2>Group2</h2>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h2>Group3</h2>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it using:

```
$('.group').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).children('.element:visible').length;
}).hide();
```

Or using jQuery selector:

```
$('.group:not(:has(.element:visible))').hide();
```

Optimized to:

```
$('.group').filter(':not(:has(.element:visible))').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$('.group').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('.element:visible').length == 0;
}).hide();
```

example, click on child and when last one is clicked the group will disapear as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/c4vxhe2a/